# How much current can a standard THT lead support?

Tags: power

Sometimes cutting the lead of a THT resistor can be useful as a jumper or any other connection. Most THT resistors are rated 0.25 W, but if they fail it's always the resistor itself which gives out the smoke, not the leads. This seems to prove that the leads themselves can carry much more. How much more, approximately?

Comment: The current carrying capacity will depend on the material, wire diameter, acceptable resistance (voltage drop) and acceptable temperature rise for your application. Where are you stuck in calculating this?

Comment: @Transistor : I know it's complicated to get exact values, but I was mostly interested in a rule-of-thumb for simple DIY projects, where accuracy is not that important. For example, the leads of the most common 0.25 W resistors, will they burn out if I use them for 0.5 W as a very short jumper, to light up a bulb, or something similarly simple.

Comment: So work out the cross-sectional area and see what current (not watts) similar sized conductors are rated for.

Comment: Technically it can carry as much current as it will take to melt the steel lead. Similar to bare, uninsulated wire. But like most wire, insulated or otherwise, the limiting factor is not the conductor itself but the thing touching the conductor which gets damaged at a far lower temperature. For wire it is the the insulation and in this case it's the PCB itself that will get damaged by the hot lead before the lead itself.

Answer (score 0):

They're typically made of plated steel so they're not nearly as good conductivity-wise as copper, but generally a 1/4-W resistor will have leads good for several amperes without issue.

Answer (score 0):

Given you will be soldering to the leads, you need to remain cooler than 200 ° C or the solder (lead-tin which is durable, or the fragile and tin-whisker-growing ROHS) will yield and start to release the lead.

Thus your PCB foil area, aka the ability to REMOVE heat from the leads, will be your limiting factor.

A square of standard PCB copper foil has 70 ° C per watt thermal resistance.

however, if you consider the solder pad as a square in the middle of 8 other squares, then you should be able to remove heat thru at last 5 of those 8 squares.

Given the 5 heat paths, the thermal resistance will be 70/5 == 14 ° C per watt.

And the other end of the lead can also dump heat into the PCB copper, thus
your thermal resistance will be 14/2 == 7 ° C per watt.

What level of current?

We are allowed 200 ° C rise. R_thermal is 7. Our power dissipated is 200/7 = 28 watts.

What current? P = I^2 * R. Assume R is 0.01 ohm.

- 28 watts == I * I * R
- I * I == 28/0.01 == 2,800

Thus I == 50+ amps

Its your job to keep the PCB foil at room temperature.